# Tell me why I shouldn't do this: Sinatra API with Full JS/HTML Frontend

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, sinatra, web

I'm about to be designing a social website that must be able to handle a high volume of users.

Here's how I want to design it:

- Sinatra on the backend with a full REST api to do all of the operations on the website
- JQuery/HTML front end web app that communicates exclusively with the REST API

In this way, I only have to make one central API that other apps (iPhone, Android) app will communicate with.

Also, it seems like it will be less load on the server, since the server only has to serve the minimum amount of info and everything else is done client side.

How come more sites aren't done this way?

Why wouldn't I want to do this?  It seems like a good idea to me...

Comment: Probably because this system would not be functional _at all_ for user agents that don't support Javascript. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript.

Comment: True, but let's say realistically I don't care about that -- I mean, nowadays such a high percentage of the web relies on JavaScript, does it *really* matter?

Comment: It matters to me (because I sometimes use `links`) and it _should_ also matter to you if you care about accessibility and machine-readability of your website (say, because you want your site to be found by search engines or you want users to distribute links into your site). Personally, I really like being able to simply parse HTML when I want to extract information automatically from a web page, and not having to start an actual browser instance to get all the contents loaded dynamically.

Comment: Except from all this, your assumption that this would put less load on the web server is plain wrong. Modern caching techniques make it possible that you often don't need to recreate HTML content dynamically on the server side. However, if you need multiple HTTP requests to put together a single page, this is much less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Because it is [fragile](http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/02/gawker-learns-the-hard-way-why-hash-bang-urls-are-evil/) and search engines won't index your content.

Answer (score 0):

37signals are working on a framework called Cinco for this kind of architecture:

http://thinkvitamin.com/code/javascript/37signals-cinco-framework-to-be-open-sourced/

But if you stick to just jQuery I think you'd miss a lot things you take for granted when using a framework, which you might have to re-implement. But it really depends on your app.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too hard to get basic functionality without JS, and after add Ajax stuff to your application. For example - you can create your API to respond as plain html markup and to respond JSON.

I like idea to do all stuff around API with JS\ajax, it maybe easy and more elegant with new technologies, it giving you more capabilites, but even google can't indexing full ajax sites now.

Read:
http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=81766